# Can't get skype to run

Tags: upgrade, skype

I can't figure this out,  under Ubuntu 14.04.1 I've had absolutly no problems.  My Printer was fine and my Skype too.  Now after I bought a newer PC with UBUNTU 14.04 on I'm just having hassles.  Can anyone tell me how I can upgrade.  OK it may sound stupid,  but I have an SSD now and don't particularly wipe it again,  so I only  want UPGRADE UBUNTU 14.04 to UBUNTU 14.04.1 .  Could anyone assist me ?

Comment: So you bought a new computer and got problems? Is that all you are going to tell us?

Comment: In a way that's correct Gunnar.  I have installed ubuntu 14.04.1 on my old PC,  bought a stronger one now.  Have ubuntu 14.10 preinstalled and it is accepting neither my Skype nor Printer.  All of this was perfect on my old PC.

Comment: Please see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/565665/how-do-i-install-skype-in-ubuntu-14-10) about how to install Skype.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command to upgrade your ubuntu 14.04 to 14.04.1

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If any issues occur try with the below to check whether your machine has 14.04.1

```
lsb_release -a
```

Hope this helps to upgrade form 14.04 to 14.04.1

Comment: Thank u very much.  Now I have Ubuntu 14.10 on my system. The problem is not solved jet.  My Printer and Skype still don't work.

Comment: sebastian@sebastian-All-Series:~$ sudo get update
[sudo] password for sebastian: 
sudo: get: command not found
sebastian@sebastian-All-Series:~$ sudo get dist-upgrade
sudo: get: command not found
sebastian@sebastian-All-Series:~$