# How do I install Skype in Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: software-installation, skype

I want to install Skype in Ubuntu 14.10. How do I do this?

Comment: Err... `sudo apt-get install skype`?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Ubuntu Software Center
2. Make sure the Canonical Partner software source is enabled:

   1. Select "Software Sources" from the Edit menu. A dialog titled "Software and Updates" should be displayed
   2. On the "Other Software" tab of the Software and Updates, make sure the "Canonical Partners" software source is checked. Click Close, and enter your administrative password if prompted to do so.
3. Back in the Ubuntu Software Center, you should see an "In Progress" indicator if you had to enable the Canonical Partners software source. This operation is querying the new software source; wait for this operation to complete before proceeding.
4. When the operation is complete, type "skype" into the search field in the upper right-hand corner of the dialog. Select the first hit ("Client for Skype VOIP and instant messaging service") and click the Install button. Enter your administrative password when prompted to do so.

Once the installation process is complete, Skype should be available from the Unity Dash or the Applications menu under the Internet submenu.

Answer (score -1):

The [Ubuntu Desktop Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-chat-skype.html) is an excellent source of info for this kind of question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Aaron: Yeah, I know that's the convention here with respect to links. But this is not any link, it's a link to the official desktop guide which is both shipped as a package with every Ubuntu installation and published on the web. It's also actively maintained. To me, it's a natural first hand source for basic questions such as the question at hand. There is no competition going on between the official docs and Ask Ubuntu, is there? So in this case I will let it stand as is.